# Как сделать `position: fixed` без последствий?

Tags: html, css, position

Если я задаю моему горизонтальному меню `position: fixed`, то тогда все отступы начинаются с самого верхнего левого угла страницы. Получается так, будто этого меню и нет вовсе. Но это очень мешает мне при адаптации. Как сделать `position: fixed` так, чтобы он воспринимался как блок, и в том месте уже нельзя было размещать другие блоки, а только ниже?

Comment: делать fixed в какм-то блоке (с вашими настройками)...ну и чутка подстроить тож придется

Comment: Добавьте код, чтобы наглядно продемонстрировать ошибку

Comment: для body сделай padding-top = высоте меню

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* The navigation bar */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
}
    
/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
    
/* Change background on mouse-over */
.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
    
/* Main content */
.main {
  margin-top: 30px; /* Add a top margin to avoid content overlay */
}
```

```html
<html>

    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="main">
      <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    </div>

</html>
```